# Why am I unable to access the products fetched from redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

My product list reducer looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
    products: [],

    productListSidebars: [],
    banners: ['enjoy.png', 'account.png']
}

export const ProductListReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case SET_PRODUCTS:
        const newState = state;
        newState.products = action.payload;
        console.log('newState', newState)
        return newState;
    }
}
```

When I log props.productList retrieved from the store to the console in the render method of the component as follows:

```
render() {
    console.log('props.prodList ', this.props.productList)
}
```

It shows the following:

```
{products: Array(0), productListSidebars: Array(3), banners: Array(2)}
```

As you can see it says the array props.productList.products contains 0 data. However when I expand props.productList in the console, it shows that props.productList.products actually contains 4 products.

```
props.prodList  
{products: Array(0), productListSidebars: Array(3), banners: Array(2)}
products: Array(4)
0: {images: Array(1), categories: Array(0), _id: "5db6fc687c213e556144ae7b", name: "Signature Gold 
Collection Tailored Fit Herringbone Suit", price: 990, …}
1: {images: Array(1), categories: Array(0), _id: "5db6fd127c213e556144aecd", name: "Executive 
Collection Tailored Fit Suit", price: 790, …}
2: {images: Array(1), categories: Array(0), _id: "5db6fd997c213e556144aef5", name: "Executive 
Collection Traditional Fit Suit", price: 690, …}
3: {images: Array(5), categories: Array(0), _id: "5db6fa6c7c213e556144ad28", name: "Signature Gold 
Collection Tailored Fit Suit", price: 960, …}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
productListSidebars: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
banners: (2) ["enjoy.png", "bank-account.png"]
__proto__: Object
```

When I try to access the products as shown below, it gives me an empty array even though there are 4 products as shown above:

```
const { products } = this.props.productList;
console.log('products', products)
```

Comment: "However when I expand props.productList in the console, it shows that props.productList.products actually contains 4 products." When are you doing it? On a  breakpoint? and when you look at console.log('props.prodList ', this.props.productList), which consists zero elements? On a breakpoint or after code is completed? In console after console.log you see the last state of object, if elements would be removed later than you called console.log finally it will show an empty array

Comment: I am logging to the console in the render method of the component. There is no other call to the store so the data should not change.

Comment: So you make a breakpoint in render method and watch it in watch window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates **must** be immutable, you can't just mutate the `state` directly.

[immutable-update-patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns/#immutable-update-patterns)

```js
switch (action.type) {
  case SET_PRODUCTS:
    return {
      ...state,
      products: action.payload
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with redux, but in vanilla RxJS if you are not subscribed for changes to your products list when an action is performed you will not receive updates because the list should be fully encapsulated in the store and you only receive a copy, not a reference.